# Is there a way to display all books in a series in this database? Possibly using CONCAT()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database which is supposed to work as a library management system. Basically, I have books with id's that are connected in a table called "prequel". The table has two columns: "resid" and "prequelid". If a row has resid = B101 and prequelid = B100 it means that B100 is the prequel of B101. I want to write a query that For each book series, present a table that shows the name of each book and its sequel(s) and prequel(s) which is shown with arrows. The table should present the series, the total length of the series and the total number of pages. (There is a "pages" attribute in the bookinfo table which is shown below). resid and prequelid have the domain CHAR(5). isbn is VARCHAR(13), title is VARCHAR(50) and pages is int.

Example of what I want it to look like:

```
The Fellowship of the Ring => The Two Towers => The Return of the King | 3 | 1191
```

Below I will supply info about the 3 tables needed to write the query! I hope somebody can help with this :) Perhaps it can be done with CONCAT() or some recursive method?

```
resid | prequelid
-------+-----------
 B1003 | B1002
 B1004 | B1003
 B5002 | B5001
 B5003 | B5002
 B5004 | B5003
 B5005 | B5004
 B5006 | B5005
 B5007 | B5006
(8 rows)
```

```
 resid |     isbn
-------+---------------
 B4592 | 9780134154367
 B4591 | 9780321781079
 B5002 | 0747538492
 B5003 | 0747542155
 B5004 | 074754624X
 B5006 | 0747581088
 B5007 | 0545010225
 B1002 | 9780261103252
 B1003 | 9780618002238
 B1004 | 9780345339737
 B7701 | 9780812416800
 B6871 | 9780062409850
 B5001 | 0747532699
 B5002 | 0747538492
 B5003 | 0747542155
 B5004 | 074754624X
 B5005 | 0747551006
 B5005 | 0747551006
 B5006 | 0747581088
 B7010 | 9780679417392
 B5002 | 0747538492
 B5003 | 0747542155
 B5004 | 074754624X
 B5005 | 0747551006
 B5006 | 0747581088
(25 rows)
```

```
                   title                   |     isbn      | pages
-------------------------------------------+---------------+-------
 Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban  | 0747542155    |   317
 Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire       | 074754624X    |   636
 Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix | 0747551006    |   766
 Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince    | 0747581088    |   607
 Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows      | 0545010225    |   607
 Nineteen Eighty-Four                      | 9780679417392 |   328
 To Kill a Mockingbird                     | 9780812416800 |   281
 Calculus                                  | 9780134154367 |  1026
 Calculus                                  | 9780321781079 |  1026
 Go Set a Watchman                         | 9780062409850 |   278
 The Fellowship of the Ring                | 9780261103252 |   423
 Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone  | 0747532699    |   423
 The Two Towers                            | 9780618002238 |   352
 The Return of the King                    | 9780345339737 |   416
 Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets   | 0747538492    |   251
(15 rows)
```

Comment: This asks for a ```RECURSIVE WITH``` statement. But a question to your DB design: Your table ```prequel``` might have multiple prequels for a book.. How do you want to handle this? Or are you using a ```UNIQUE``` constraint here? You could also save this with the title or the resource-identifier together.. Anyways, there might also appear cyclic dependencies.. But you can "stop" after a cycle using the ```RECURSIVE WITH``` approach

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Islingre ! I understand that my design solution might not be top notch. I'm a beginner at SQL! Perhaps you could come up with a SQL query that solves my issue? It would be a lot of help in my learning. Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Islingre noted, there are dangers to this approach due to cyclic dependencies or multiple prequels.  However, the basic idea is to use a recursive CTE:

```
create table prequel (resid char(5), prequelid char(5));
 insert into prequel values ('B1003','B1002'),
('B1004','B1003'),
('B5002','B5001'),
('B5003','B5002'),
('B5004','B5003'),
('B5005','B5004'),
('B5006','B5005'),
('B5007','B5006');

create table isbn (resid char(5), isbn varchar(13));
insert into isbn VALUES ('B4592','9780134154367'),
('B4591','9780321781079'),
('B5002','0747538492'),
('B5003','0747542155'),
('B5004','074754624X'),
('B5006','0747581088'),
('B5007','0545010225'),
('B1002','9780261103252'),
('B1003','9780618002238'),
('B1004','9780345339737'),
('B7701','9780812416800'),
('B6871','9780062409850'),
('B5001','0747532699'),
('B5002','0747538492'),
('B5003','0747542155'),
('B5004','074754624X'),
('B5005','0747551006'),
('B5005','0747551006'),
('B5006','0747581088'),
('B7010','9780679417392'),
('B5002','0747538492'),
('B5003','0747542155'),
('B5004','074754624X'),
('B5005','0747551006'),
('B5006','0747581088');

create table book (title varchar(50), isbn varchar(13), pages int);
insert into book values ('Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban','0747542155','317'),
('Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire','074754624X','636'),
('Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix','0747551006','766'),
('Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince','0747581088','607'),
('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows','0545010225','607'),
('Nineteen Eighty-Four','9780679417392','328'),
('To Kill a Mockingbird','9780812416800','281'),
('Calculus','9780134154367','1026'),
('Calculus','9780321781079','1026'),
('Go Set a Watchman','9780062409850','278'),
('The Fellowship of the Ring','9780261103252','423'),
('Harry Potter and the Philosopher''s Stone','0747532699','423'),
('The Two Towers','9780618002238','352'),
('The Return of the King','9780345339737','416'),
('Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets','0747538492','251');

WITH recursive prequels(resid, first_book, prequelid, num_books, path) AS (
  SELECT resid, prequelid, prequelid, 1, array[prequelid::text]
  FROM prequel p1
  -- the prequel of this book should not be the prequel of something else
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (select from prequel p2 WHERE p1.prequelid = p2.resid)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT prequel.resid, p.first_book, prequel.prequelid, p.num_books + 1, path || prequel.prequelid::text
  FROM prequel, prequels p
  WHERE p.resid = prequel.prequelid
  AND num_books <= 50 --drop out of cte if there are recursive dependencies
),
  -- Get the complete series
  series AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (first_book)
    first_book,
    path || resid::text AS path -- We are missing the final book in the series, so add it here.
  FROM prequels
  ORDER BY first_book, num_books desc
), book_info AS (
 -- Get rid of duplicates, which exist in the isbn table
 SELECT DISTINCT first_book,
        title,
        i,
        pages
   FROM series
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM unnest(path) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(resid, i)) sub
   JOIN isbn ON  sub.resid = isbn.resid
   JOIN book on book.isbn = isbn.isbn
) 
SELECT string_agg(title, ' => ' ORDER BY i),
       count(*),
       sum(pages)
FROM book_info
GROUP BY first_book;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This idea seems great, but when I try it out it doesn't work! I get the following error: ERROR:  recursive query "prequels" column 5 has type character(5)[] in non-recursive term but type bpchar[] overall
LINE 2:   SELECT resid, prequelid, prequelid, 1, array[prequelid]
                                                 ^
HINT:  Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.

I do understand my database design might not be perfect, but it is too late to change now since I would have to rewrite all previous queries for this assingment.

Comment: You'll need to cast one of the columns so they match.  You didn't give your table definitions, so I had to guess about the types.  Try changing the query to use `array[prequelid::text]` and, in the recursive part, `path || prequel.prequelid::text`

Comment: thanks! I'll try it. prequelid is defined with domain CHAR(5), so a 5 character long text string essentially!

Comment: I edited the query and table definitions to match your description.  It should work fine now.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted! Can't thank you enough for this @Jeremy