# Show all books in a series based on prequels

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with information about books. I need to create a table where every row is a list of the whole series looking like this

```
Series |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The lord of the Rings: The fellowship of the Ring => The Two Towers => The return of the King | 3 | 9250
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Harry Potter: …
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So a concated string with the entire series | series length | total pages

In my database I have bookid, title, prequeltitle, pages

This is as far as I've gotten

```
With recursive bookseries (title, precededby) as (
Select title, precededby
From books
Where resourceid = 126
Union
Select b.title, b.precededby
From books b
Inner join bookseries bs on bs.precededby = b.title 
)
Select * from bookseries;
```

```
 title                             |                          precededby
--------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows                         | Harry potter and the Half-Blood Prince
 Harry potter and the Half-Blood Prince                       | Harry Potter and the Order of the Pheonix
 Harry Potter and the Order of the Pheonix                    | Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
 Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire                          | Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
 Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban                     | Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
 Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets                      | Harry Potter and the Philosphers Stone
 Harry Potter and the Philosphers Stone                       |
(7 rows)
```

the resourceid=126 is just to get the final book from my database

```
CREATE TABLE Books ( 
ResourceID int PRIMARY KEY, 
Title char(60), 
pages int,
Isbn char (30), 
AuthorID int REFERENCES Authors(AuthorID), 
Edition int, 
Language char (30),
Publisher char (60), 
DateOfPublication date, 
PrecededBy char (60)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display all books in a series in this database? Possibly using CONCAT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807835/is-there-a-way-to-display-all-books-in-a-series-in-this-database-possibly-using)

Comment: Post your schema and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @alexham it's not a lot yet. Really struggling to understand recursion here

Answer (score 0):

You are not far from what's needed. Instead of CONCAT you need the [STRING_AGG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-aggregate.html) function and a slight change to to the recursive CTE. I'll show the results below, but first a couple suggestions on the table.  < br/>

1. Don't use the CHAR type instead use VARCHAR or TEXT. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-character.html). This actually applies to all tables in your database.
2. Don't use the book title for PrecededBy. Instead make it an integer that contains the ResourceID of the predecessor and a FK to it. That insures the predecssor actually exists.

Now the query:

```
with recursive bookseries (title, pages, seq) as 
   (select title,pages, 1
      from books
     where title = 'Harry Potter and the Philosphers Stone'
    union all
    select b.title, b.pages, seq+1
      from books b
      join bookseries bs on b.precededby = bs.title 
   ) 
select string_agg( title, ' -> '  order by seq) as book_series
     , max(seq) number_of_books
     , sum(pages) total_pages 
  from bookseries;
```